# A simple Javascript write method

Tags: javascript, oop

Okay, this may be a silly question but I'm still on my path to learning OO javascript like a pro, so please don't laugh if this question is a little dumb... okay, say I have a very simple object like this

```
var myObject = {

    write:function(){
        return 'this is a string';

    }
}
```

now if add the following outside my object (please note I have the appropriate Div in my webpage):

```
document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML = myObject.write();
```

the innerHTML of my div is filled with the string 'this is a string', however if I just add the following to my script (outside the object): `myObject.write()`

nothing is returned? Can some one tell me why and how I could write to the page ( not using `document.write(myObject.write())` ) to output the string to the page. If this can't be done please let me know why...

sorry if this is a really simple / stupid question but I am learning.

Here's the full thing to help...

```
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>

<div id='myDiv'></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

var myObject = {

    write:function(){
        return 'this is a string 2';

    }
}

//document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML = myObject.write();
myObject.write();

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calling `myObject.write()` returns the value. Since you're not catching and processing the return value, nothing happens.

Another method to write content to your document:

```
<body>
<script>document.write(myObject.write())</script>
...</body> <!--document.write ONLY works as desired when the document loads.
       When you call document.write() after the document has finished initiating,
       nothing will happen, or the page unloads-->
```

Comment: @Mark -- haha that is true, did not realize that you wanted such a simple answer ^_^

Comment: Hey! I said no document.write, don't make me mark your answer down Rob L, LOL! Thanks too Neal

Comment: I design my answers to be useful to the asker, and to future readers. This site gets much traffic from Google and other search engines.

Answer (score 0):

```
var myObject = {
    obj: (function(){ return document.getElementById('myDiv');})(),
         //^^set object to write to
    write:function(str){
        this.obj.innerHTML += str;
        //^^add the string to this object
    }
}

myObject.write('hello there');
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/k3Ma5/

Comment: What's the purpose of the self-invoking function here?

Comment: @pimvdb to get the object immediately